# How to get the decorator handle arbitrary arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, decorator, keyword-argument

I am trying to understand decorators. I want to define a decorator that can handle any arbitrary argument. I am trying the following:

```
def a_decorator_passing_arbitrary_arguments(function_to_decorate):
    def a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments(*args,**kwargs):
        print('The positional arguments are', args)
        print('The keyword arguments are', kwargs)
        function_to_decorate(*args)
    return a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments
```

This is based on [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decorators-python) and it supposedly handles any type of argument. However when I pass only keyword arguments I get the following output with function `f(a,b,c)`:

```
@a_decorator_passing_arbitrary_arguments
def f(a,b,c):
    print("The arguments here are the following: {0}, {1}, {2}.".format(a,b,c))

f(a='ali', b='emma', c='t')
```

The output:

```
The positional arguments are ()
The keyword arguments are {'a': 'ali', 'b': 'emma', 'c': 't'}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cc5ee8d7120a> in <module>
----> 1 f(a='ali', b='emma', c='t')

<ipython-input-1-af03800e2abd> in a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments(*args, **kwargs)
      3         print('The positional arguments are', args)
      4         print('The keyword arguments are', kwargs)
----> 5         function_to_decorate(*args)
      6     return a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments

TypeError: f() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
```

How can I avoid getting this error in the case when all the variables are passed as keyword arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently only passing on the positional arguments, not the keyword arguments as well, to the wrapped function.

```
def a_decorator_passing_arbitrary_arguments(function_to_decorate):
    def a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments(*args,**kwargs):
        print('The positional arguments are', args)
        print('The keyword arguments are', kwargs)
        # function_to_decorate(*args)  # Wrong
        return function_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)  # Right
    return a_wrapper_accepting_arbitrary_arguments
```

(You should also return whatever `function_to_decorate` returns from the wrapper.)